# How to find the joomla versions of all sites on my server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, web-server, joomla

I have a windows server 2008 r2 and i have uploaded sites there. I need an automatic way to check what version of joomla is per site. The best is to have 1 script and after running i want to see this output:

`[site] [version]` my problem is to check for my clients if they have upload or didn't update to last version for security breach. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for and parse the `version.php` file.

The location has changed a few times, but you could search in the places you know it should be.  If you can't find a valid `version.php` then have your script alert for that site/instance.  Once you find the file check that is valid.  Your check could be a simple sha256() comparison to the current stable release, or you could actually check the version number in the PHP file.

See this thread for locations for some [older versions](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=248890) version.php.